# "Cannot load Java class" in JRuby

Tags: jruby

I want to integrate a very simple Java file into my JRuby app. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Simple.java:

```
package com.mypackage;

public class Simple {
  public void foo() {
    System.out.println("foo called");
  }
}
```

I compile it with "javac Simple.java" 
Then I create a jar file with "jar cf mylib.jar Simple.class"

test.rb:

```
require 'java'
require "mylib.jar"
java_import 'com.mypackage.Simple'
```

When I run it with "ruby test.rb" I get the following error:

```
NameError: cannot load Java class com.mypackage.Simple
     for_name at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:1286
     get_proxy_class at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:34
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
My JRuby version is: jruby 1.7.16.1 (1.9.3p392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. I have forgotten to put the Simple class into the folder structure com/mypackage/Simple. Java was therefore not able to find the class.